# ¿Cuándo estuvo en activo el verbo "sorrabar"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, historia

Ayer descubrí una maravillosa palabra en el DLE:

> **[sorrabar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YQdSxyz)**
>
> De *so<sup>3</sup>* y *rabo*.
>
> 1. tr. Besar a un animal debajo del rabo. Era castigo infamante que se imponía antiguamente a los ladrones de perros.
> 2. tr. Rogar con sumisión.

Quedeme alucinado con esa primera acepción. Lo curioso es que fui a buscarla en el NTLLE y su primera aparición es en el *Diccionario de Autoridades*, pero aunque el ejemplo que dan es correcto, no lo es la acepción:

> SORRABAR. v.a. Lo mismo que derrabar, ò cortar el rabo à algun animal. Es voz antiquada. *Si le tomaren con algun can furtado, que gelo fagan sorrabar, è que torne el can à su dueño.*

El ejemplo no tiene sentido si la acepción es la que dice: ¿para qué iba a tener un ladrón que cortarle el rabo a un perro antes de devolverlo? Esta acepción se corrigió en la edición de 1780 del DLE, donde aparece ya con la acepción actual.

Sin embargo, y dado que la palabra ya estaba anticuada en el siglo XVIII, ¿cuándo estuvo en activo? ¿Qué ejemplos se encuentran en el CORDE de esta palabra usada con esa primera y humillante acepción?

Answer (score 3):

El propio ejemplo que cita el *Diccionario de Autoridades* corresponde al Libro 1, capítulo 34 del [**Libro de la montería**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libro_de_la_monter%C3%ADa) ([Edición digital](http://fondosdigitales.us.es/fondos/libros/313/209/libro-de-la-monteria-que-mando-escrevir-el-muy-alto-y-muy-poderoso-rey-don-alonso-de-castilla-y-de-leon-vltimo-de-este-nombre/leer/)), escrito por encargo de Alfonso XI de Castilla (1311 - 1350), luego **ya era conocida y utilizada desde al menos principios del siglo XIV**. La página concreta en que figura el ejemplo se puede consultar también [**aquí**](https://books.google.es/books?id=9vUo_Q0FocQC&pg=PP42#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Curiosamente:

- la palabra **desapareció del diccionario de la RAE** durante casi 100 años (1817 - 1925)
- cuando reapareció en 1925 **no incluía la acepción del beso**, sino la "de corte de la cola" (como en el *Diccionario de Autoridades*
- la **acepción del beso "resucitó" en la edición del DLE de 1984** y siguientes
- **ninguno** de los diccionarios que no son de la RAE accesibles por medio del NTLLE (Terreros y Pando 1788, Salvá 1846, Gaspar y Roig 1855, etc.) **recogen la acepción del "beso"**.

Comment: En el enlace a la edición digital se dice que el libro lo encargó "el muy alto y muy poderoso Rey Don Alonso de Castilla y de Leon, último de este nombre", no Alfonso. En la Wikipedia se dice que está escrito en el siglo XIV, pero entonces ¿cómo es posible que en la [página 234](http://fondosdigitales.us.es/fondos/libros/313/234/libro-de-la-monteria-que-mando-escrevir-el-muy-alto-y-muy-poderoso-rey-don-alonso-de-castilla-y-de-leon-vltimo-de-este-nombre/leer/) se hable de la montería en las Indias, y se mencione expresamente Cuba, Puertorrico y Nueva España? El libro debe ser del siglo XVI.

Comment: Además, el español del libro se entiende demasiado bien como para ser un texto del siglo XIV. Si buscas en el CORDE textos de ese siglo el español difiere mucho de lo que se escribía en el XVI. Te lo confirma la portada del libro, que dice que se escribió en 1582.

Comment: Investigando un poco más, veo que en la página 209 sí se dice que el texto original fue encargado por el rey Alfonso (ahora sí), que reinó desde el año 1312, por lo que el texto digitalizado debe ser una adaptación posterior, y las páginas posteriores a la 209 debieron de ser añadidos a la obra original. ¿Podemos estar seguros entonces de que "sorrabar" se usaba en el siglo XIV? ¿O se usó como parte de dicha adaptación?

Answer (score 2):

Buscando en el CORDE textos que contengan palabras que comiencen por *sorrab-* se encuentran varios casos, pero muchos hacen referencia a su acepción como "rogar con sumisión". El más reciente lo recoge Gonzalo Correas con su peculiar estilo:

> *A sorrabar a otros, ke ansí llaman al rogar i pedir kon sumisión.*
>
> Gonzalo Correas, "Vocabulario de refranes y frases proverbiales", 1627 (España).

Los textos que recogen el otro uso de *sorrabar* se encuentran (aunque no muchos) en los siglos XV y XVI:

> *Señores, si ellos me quiebran costilla,
>
>   que den en mis ojos catorze pujeses;
>
>   pero si les quiebro sus rezios paveses,
>
>   que amos sorraben mi mula pardilla.*
>
> Juan Alfonso de Baena, "Poesías [Cancionero de Baena]", 1406-a1435 (España).

Se ve su uso como insulto, que se recoge también en el siguiente texto:

> *PETIJÁN
>
>   Nani, rien:
>
>   ¿vus ete vus sabi bien
>
>   notre studi de París?
>
>   FRANCISCO
>
>   Mal garrotazo me os den
>
>   si entiendo lo que dezís.
>
>   PETIJÁN
>
>   Mon ami,
>
>   per la xar de notre Di,
>
>   lo gran Roy y lo Delphín...
>
>   FRANCISCO
>
>   Ora, por amor de mí,
>
>   que sorrabes un mastín.*
>
> Bartolomé de Torres Naharro, "Comedia Tinellaria [Propaladia]", 1517 (España).

Esto último de "anda y vete a sorrabar un mastín" me lo apunto por si algún día se lo tengo que decir a alguien.

No hay textos mucho más allá, el más reciente es también el más explícito:

> *Por tu fe, que me sorrabes.*
>
> Jaime de Huete, "Comedia Tesorina", c1528 (España).

Comment: Puede ser difícil encontrar ejemplos más antiguos en el CORDE porque antes se escribía, parece, con la "S alta"